# untar content of folder from tar.gz archive that gets data from STDOUT (wget)

Tags: server, tar, wget, pipe, stdout

I want to extract the **content** of a single folder from a `tar.gz` archive that gets its input from the STDOUT of `wget`.

My command looks like this:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/file.tar.gz | tar -C /path/Where/ToExtract/To -xzf - folderToUntar
```

Unfortunately what I get is the main folder of the archive, not the contents of `folderToUntar`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay got it... using `--strip-components=1` does the job for me.